# MySQL didn't prompt any window to enter host name and and password during installation

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I downloaded and installed MySQL yesterday, I chose full setup, it installed all the required software and then directly took me to finish windows. But now when I try to connect to server, it asks for hostname and password. Some please help me with it.

Comment: then your hostname would be localhost and password you can check in log file.

Comment: Please have a look on below link which will be helpful for your case.

https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-install-mysql-database-server-8-0-19-on-windows-10/

Answer (score 0):

If you installed it locally use localhost as the hostname.  The default user for MySQL is root and by default it has no password.  If you need reset the password it depends on what OS you are running: https://dbschema.com/2020/04/21/mysql-default-username-password/